# Adding suffix if does not exist (bash)

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to find the best way to add a suffix to string (in bash) if it doesn't already exist.

I first came up with this:

```
case "$R" in
    *.git ) ;;
    * ) R=$R.git ;;
esac
```

Which works. But is cumbersome.

Then thought about this:

```
R=${R%.git}.git
```

Which is nice and compact and neat.

Are the any other options? Any gotchas I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5):

```
[[ $r == *.git ]] || r+=.git
```

would be my preferred method.

```
shopt -s extglob
case $r in !(*.git)) r+=.git; esac
```

might be a better `case` method. Your second method is probably good enough if it is assured that `R` is set and not null. Other possibilities include:

```
${r:+'declare'} r="${r%.git}.git"
r=${r%.git}.git ${r:+'true'}
```

For POSIX sh, either of your ways are fine, though you should consider not using all-caps variable names.

Comment: His original produces ".git"; your workaround does not set `r` for me.

Comment: @chepner That's the point. `r=foo.gi; ${r:+declare r=${r%.git}.git}; echo "$r"` produces `foo.gi.git`. However if r is unset or null, then the expansion becomes nothing and the declare command isn't executed. This prevents r from being set if it wasn't set to begin with. If you wanted `r` to become `.git`, only if `r` is null but not unset, then remove the colon from the expansion.

Comment: +1 Thanks - I hadn't thought about R not being set. My script does check arguments in other ways, but this is something to be aware of.